# Adding to class in HTML string stored as JavaScript variable

Tags: javascript, html, getelementbyid

I have an HTML string stored as a JavaScript variable in my js code:

```
myHTML= `<div id="type1-div"><p id="type1-lbl"> </p>\
                    <img id="type1-img" class="center stim" src="${myFolder}/photo${n}.png"></div>\
                    <div id="type2-div"><p id="type2-lbl"> </p>\
                    <img id = "type2-img" class="center stim" src="${myFolder}/photo${m}.png"</div>`;
```

I then want to add to the class of these elements based on certain conditions and change some of their contents based on their id.
These, for instance, didn't work since (I think?) myHTML is not part of the HTML document yet.

```
document.getElementById("type1-div").classList.add("top");
document.getElementById(id).innerHTML = "TOP PARAGRAPH"
```

An example desired desired output would be such that myHTML is now:

```
 `<div id="type1-div" class="top"><p id="type1-lbl">TOP PARAGRAPH</p>\
                        <img id="type1-img" class="center stim" src="${myFolder}/photo${n}.png"></div>\
                        <div id="type2-div" class="bottom"><p id="type2-lbl">BOTTOM PARAGRAPH </p>\
                        <img id = "type2-img" class="center stim" src="${myFolder}/photo${m}.png"</div>`;
```

Any ideas on how to achieve this? Thank you!

Comment: `document.getElementById(id).innerHTML = new HTML`, what is `HTML`? Do you mean `document.getElementById(id).innerHTML = myHTML`?

Comment: You can create a `DocumentFragment` and use `myHTML` as its `innerHTML`. Then you can use DOM methods on that.

Comment: @Phix sorry, my bad. Edited now!

Comment: The node has to be in the DOM to get it by id. Perhaps you want to create Elements like `const varNameHere = document.createElement(tagNameHere)` instead, so you can have the Element before it's appended to the DOM. You can attach Events to the variable directly then, as well. I would also use `.textContent =` instead of `.innerHTML = `.